# MATLAB - set title

Tags: matlab

is any way to get string from this type?:

I would like to set title from this code:

`f = inline('(x-3).^2 - 1');`

and for title:

`figure(1)
...
title(func2str(f))
...`

it's any way to set title direct from `inline`?

Comment: cniak, what exactly do you mean by "direct from `inline`"? `inline` just defines the function, it can't do anything else. You can of course write a function that does these two things. Also note: According to the help in R2013a, "inline will be removed in a future release. Use anonymous functions instead."

Comment: i'm searching any way to set title by any func whose collect string from `inline` and create string which can be add to title :)

Comment: But that's exactly what your code does, using `func2str` and `title`. So what's missing?

Comment: problem: it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by capturing the figure handle and editing the title from it.

```
fg_title = 'my figure title';
fg = figure; 
set(fg, 'name', fg_title); //set the figure title
```

but the `figure 1` text will still be preset at the title bar, if you want to remove it just disable numbered title:

```
set fg, 'NumberTitle', 'off'); //disable numbered title
```